# How can I add an option to enter a digital hand signature to my form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, digital-signature, signature

I'm currently working on a JavaScript + react project and I want to add a field for drawing personal signature as a pdf or in some other format I could save to my db.

Is there a package for it or I can do it? Thanks to all the help.

Comment: Could use react canvas and save the drawing but I very much doubt the legal value of all this compare to solution like docusign and so on

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question is too broad, and library requests are off topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I implemented recently. You can achieve it using `canvas`.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const MOVE = "move";
const DOWN = "down";
const UP = "up";
const OUT = "out";

const CaptureSignature = () => {
  let canvas,
    drawingContext,
    isMouseDownOrTouchStart = false,
    previousX = 0,
    currentX = 0,
    previousY = 0,
    currentY = 0,
    isDrawingADot = false;

  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  const initializeDrawing = () => {
    canvas = canvasRef.current;
    drawingContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const findXYMOVE = (e) => {
      findXY(MOVE, e);
    };
    const findXYDOWN = (e) => {
      findXY(DOWN, e);
    };
    const findXYUP = (e) => {
      findXY(UP, e);
    };
    const findXYOUT = (e) => {
      findXY(OUT, e);
    };

    // add mouse events
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", findXYMOVE);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", findXYDOWN);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", findXYUP);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", findXYOUT);

    // add touch events
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", findXYMOVE);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", findXYDOWN);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchend", findXYUP);

    return () => {
      // remove mouse events
      canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", findXYMOVE);
      canvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", findXYDOWN);
      canvas.removeEventListener("mouseup", findXYUP);
      canvas.removeEventListener("mouseout", findXYOUT);

      // remove touch events
      canvas.removeEventListener("touchmove", findXYMOVE);
      canvas.removeEventListener("touchstart", findXYDOWN);
      canvas.removeEventListener("touchend", findXYUP);
    };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeDrawing();
  }, []);

  const draw = () => {
    drawingContext.beginPath();
    drawingContext.moveTo(previousX, previousY);
    drawingContext.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
    drawingContext.lineWidth = 1;
    drawingContext.strokeStyle = "black";
    drawingContext.stroke();
    drawingContext.closePath();
  };

  const getPosition = (canvas, evt) => {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
      scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width,
      scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;

    return {
      x:
        ((evt?.clientX || (evt.touches && evt.touches["0"]?.clientX)) -
          rect.left) *
        scaleX,
      y:
        ((evt?.clientY || (evt.touches && evt.touches["0"]?.clientY)) -
          rect.top) *
        scaleY
    };
  };

  const findXY = (action, e) => {
    const { x, y } = getPosition(canvas, e);

    if (action === DOWN) {
      previousX = currentX;
      previousY = currentY;
      currentX = x;
      currentY = y;

      isMouseDownOrTouchStart = true;
      isDrawingADot = true;
      if (isDrawingADot) {
        drawingContext.beginPath();
        drawingContext.fillRect(currentX, currentY, 1, 1);
        drawingContext.closePath();
        isDrawingADot = false;
      }
    }
    if (action === UP || action === OUT) {
      isMouseDownOrTouchStart = false;
    }
    if (action === MOVE) {
      if (isMouseDownOrTouchStart) {
        previousX = currentX;
        previousY = currentY;
        currentX = x;
        currentY = y;
        draw();
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "500px", height: "500px", border: "2px solid" }}>
      <canvas style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }} ref={canvasRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CaptureSignature;
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-sun-g9526?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @SimpleLogic, check this out !!